# Intermediate MySQL query: updating table column based on separate table column value

Tags: mysql, select, sql-update

I have a table `ticketdetails` which contains a column with data that I want to copy to another table's column:

```
SELECT TicketID, MIN( StartTime ) StartTime
FROM ticketdetails
GROUP BY TicketID #might be unnecessary?
ORDER BY TicketID
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

I want the result of this query, "StartTime", to be supplied in my other table column, `tickets.TimeScheduled`, where the `TicketID` matches for both tables.

Right now I'm trying:

```
UPDATE tickets SET TimeScheduled = (
SELECT MIN( StartTime ) StartTime
FROM ticketdetails
GROUP BY TicketID
ORDER BY TicketID)
WHERE tickets.TicketID = ticketdetails.TicketID
```

I get this error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'ticketdetails.TicketID' in 'where clause'
```

I know that this column exists in my database. For some reason the query doesn't recognize the column. I think I need a `JOIN` or something, but I'm not the best with intermediate-advanced MySQL queries. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think `GROUP BY` might not be necessary? If you don't use that, you'll get the minimum time in the entire table, not the per-ticket minimums.

Comment: @Barmar woah--- totally right there. I'll be needing it for sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a join:

```
UPDATE tickets AS t
JOIN (SELECT TicketID, MIN( StartTime ) StartTime
      FROM ticketdetails
      GROUP BY TicketID) AS d ON t.TicketID = d.TicketID
SET t.TimeScheduled = d.StartTime
```

The reason you're getting an `Unknown column` error is because the `ticketdetails` table only exists in the subquery, not in the main query.

If you want to set `timeScheduled` to `NULL` if there's no matching ticket in `ticketdetails`, change `JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`.

BTW, there's no need for `ORDER BY` in the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE tickets
    SET TimeScheduled = (SELECT MIN( td.StartTime ) StartTime
                         FROM ticketdetails td
                         WHERE td.TicketID = t.TicketID
                        );
```

Comment: i don't see where you define `t`. Should it be `UPDATE tickets AS t`?

Comment: Do you need an `IFNULL` to handle the case where there's no matching ID in `ticketdetails`?

Comment: pretty sure there is always a value that correlates. Even if the `StartTime` is null, I still want to copy it over